# Container hierarchy access for jQuery elements

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

JQM elements on physical page:

```
#page_test1
    button changing page to #page_test2

#page_test2
    div #place to put something programmatically
```

to put button inside #place container I wrote the following (working) code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page_test2', function(event) {
    $('#place').empty();
    $('#place').append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="d">Dynamic button inserted by JavaScript</a>');
    $('#place').trigger('create');
});
```

Ok, but when I take an attempt to move `.on` body to script level (directly under script tag) code inside become wrong because of context loose:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page_test2', function(event) {
    addButton(); // Attempt to move widget manipulation up
});

// Widget manipulation not changed but moved outside (level up) .on
// Not working
function addButton() {
    $('#place').empty();
    $('#place').append('<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="d">Dynamic button inserted by JavaScript</a>');
    $('#place').trigger('create');
}
```

How to access JQM elements from different levels of JQM hierarchy and outside of it?

Guess it is very basic for JQM / Ajax so I will very thankful to take URL with common information.

Comment: Does anybody knows the topic?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more, I didn't get your point. However, if I'm not mistaken, you want to know the difference between `$(document).on('event', '#pageID', function()` and `$('#pageID').on('event', function()`?

Comment: To better understanding I add target script to initial message

Comment: hmmm..i understand that if you call it outside the page, it works. but if you place the code inside the page it doesn't? if so, `$('#page_test2').on('pagebeforeshow', function()` should work since it's within the same file/page.

Comment: Omar, seems strange, but target code pieces are working and produce expected results now. I didn't catch what's up but anyway thanks for patience

Comment: My pleasure. Did that work for you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28643/discussion-between-valery-bulash-and-omar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an dynamically through code outside the target page, use the the following:

```
$(document).on(event, '.selector', function() { });
```

To access an dynamically through code inside the target page, use the the following:

```
$('.selector').on(event, function() { });
```